# Decoupled or headless open-source E-Commerce CMS

Tags: cms, api

I'm planning to make website as well as app for e-commerce using a CMS.
I required the DB to be accessed from both.
CMS for e-commerce are easily available but they're embedded with the backend DB requests.
The app development needs to be done via PhoneGap/Apache Cordova, hence require API-like interaction with DB or something more secure from the front-end.

I was looking around for some Magento/WP-Ecommerce/OpenCart like system with good community & extensions available but with API interaction with DB.

To sum it:

1. I install DB on the server.
2. Put the website front-end on the server & give it necessary DB access.
3. Make App from HTML,CSS & JS either by some online available theme or customising the website front-end as the app is going to have much more features than the website or using some CMS mobile theme version & build it using PhoneGap.
   [image: decoupled architecture]
   This will help in getting a better picture of decoupling.

https://pantheon.io/decoupled-cms

http://www.onehippo.com/en/resources/blogs/2015/5/cms-decoupled-architecture.html

Comment: How about letting the CMS take care of the database, and use the CMS' APIs from your apps? Decoupling at the DB level would force you to re-implement business logic inside all apps.

Comment: Agreed, but I'd require an official API for that. Also, I'll have to make over the entire front-end (HTM,CSS,JS) for the mobile app as currently it would be integrated with php or server-side language Queries.

I just want to customise the app to add the required features & don't wanna re-invent the wheel.

Comment: So you are OK with working with an API? Pretty much all ECMS products have an API that allows building apps. If you just want to customize the app, the APIs should have far enough already.

Comment: The basic features of e-commerce app require a front-end for building into an app. 
Like for instance, I set up, OpenCart. It gives me the admin control & the front-end.


I also require a similar pre-developed responsive front-end without server side language for mobile as well.
Don't want to implement the basics.

Comment: So, any ECMS product can fill your need.

Comment: Yes, which has a separate front-end from the server.
Preferably open source & bootstrap compatible.
If possible OpenCart as I've some experience in that.

Comment: Even Magento & WP-Ecommerce/WooCommerce would do.